# how to add 10 values in array (5,2) and then compute the average of them

Tags: vb.net

Assume that there are 5 records, each containing temperature values. The first temperature value on each record represents a high temperature from weather station, and the second temperatures on each record represents a low temperature from a weather station, input these temperatures into a table TEMP (5, 2) the with high temperatures from the 5 stations in column 1 of the table, and the low temperatures of the 5 stations in column 2 of the table. After reading in all the temperatures, find and output the average high temperatures and the average low temperatures for the 5 weather stations.

Comment: Appears to be home work. Man, give it a try and then when u get stuck with something specific, we'll try to help u with that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're not a code writing service. You need to come with the code you've written and then ask us for help to fix a specific issue that you're having. There are heaps of resources on the internet that will show you how to fill arrays and read values from them. You should be able to solve this with the help of Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2D array as well as dictionary in this situation

**Using Dictionary**

```
Dim temArray As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)() '<-- declaration of dictionary 
'<--- you can get all these values from the user also
temArray.Add(31, 20)'<-- add first set of high and low temperature values
temArray.Add(28, 17)'<-- add second set of high and low temperature values
temArray.Add(27, 16)'<-- add third set of high and low temperature values
temArray.Add(22, 19)'<-- add fourth set of high and low temperature values
temArray.Add(30, 22)'<-- add fifth set of high and low temperature values
Dim avgHighTemp As Double = temArray.Keys.Sum() / 5 '<-- average high temperature 27.6
Dim avgLowTemp As Double = temArray.Values.Sum() / 5'<-- average high temperature 16.8
```

**Using 2D array**

```
    Dim temArray(,) As Integer = New Integer(4, 1) {{31, 20}, {28, 17}, {22, 19}, {30, 22}, {27, 6}}
    Dim avgHighTemp As Double = 0
    Dim avgLowTemp As Double = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        avgHighTemp += temArray(i, 0)
        avgLowTemp += temArray(i, 1)
    Next
    MsgBox("Average high temperature :" & avgHighTemp / 5)
    MsgBox("Average high temperature :" & avgLowTemp / 5)
```

Comment: A dictionary is not a good solution for this - dictionaries are key-value pairs, and the keys must be unique (not duplicates).  If you had something like city and then high and low temps, a dictionary might make more sense, because then there is an obvious correlation between the key and the value.  IMO.

Comment: that's why i suggest 2d array also